# beginner: creating existing package

Tags: slam, navigation, tutorial, hector-slam, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to modify hector_slam. So, for a rearrangeable hector_slam I think i should create and build or install hector_slam in catkin_ws right?

I looked the tutorials and got confused so much. I created catkin_ws by following http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace tutorial. Next tutorial is http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/CreatingPackage, description is how to create a NEW ros package using catkin.
But I want to create/build or install an existing package(hector_slam) so should i follow this tutorial anyway?

Thanks,

Basak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234397/beginner:-creating-existing-package/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer that i need is "overlaying". When i was looking similar questions i found this answer http://answers.ros.org/question/37764/rosed-for-read-only-files/?answer=37768#post-id-37768

Anyway i just followed overlaying workspace tutorial. http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying.

Now i am able to modify the packages (in my case hector_slam) as i want.

---

Originally posted by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) with karma: 73 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0